# Arduino Loop random amount of time

Tags: loops, random, arduino, arduino-c++

I need help looping a loop random amount of time.
For example:

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
     //Blah blah code
  }
```

This, I believe loops it 10 times. I want it to loop a random amount of times so I tried this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= random(0,1000); i++) {
     //Blah blah code
  }
```

This hasn't worked for me, and it only picks randomly when I first power the arduino. When I close it and try it again, it loops it the same amount of times as before, and so forth. My question is, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a loop present as void loop. you should not use another loop inside a loop. Try to avoid it if it is avoidable.

Here is the example code you can use for your problem.

```
long randNumber;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));  // seeding random input from analog pin , one can use any analog pin.
}

void loop() {
  randNumber = random(300);
  Serial.println(randNumber);
  delay(50);
}
```